# Make a div's background-color property fill its td parent

Tags: html, css

This is for a forum post layout. Consider this HTML:

```
<td>
 <div class="example">Content</div>
</td>
```

and this CSS:

```
div.example { background-color: #EEE; }
```

I want to change this particular td's background colour without targeting td, because there are other td elements and `:nth-child()` will affect others' posts.

Comment: can't you just add the class "example" to the td?

Comment: No. You can't modify a board's HTML structure without using Inspect element.

Comment: If you assign `div.example { background-color: #EEE; height: 100%; width: 100%; }` the background color doesn't fill the parent td?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would mean addressing/selecting the parent element which is not possible with CSS alone. You'd need javascript/jQuery for that.

Comment: What a shame. I wish the pseudo-class `:has` was finished and supported.